# dB A and dB Z (or dB SPL) Table

Tags: audio, sound, units

Does anyone have a detailed dB A to db Z (or dB SPL) table?  I have found one at http://www.cirrusresearch.co.uk/blog/2011/08/what-are-a-c-z-frequency-weightings/ and at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470869253.app4/pdf.  Is there one with values for 3000 Hz and 6000 Hz (and as many other values as possible)?  I know it is not possible to convert between dB A and dB SPL, but I am trying to look for a table of corresponding values.  Since Z-weighting subtracts 0 every time, a highly detailed A-weighting table would be good too.

Comment: What precision do you require? If you'd be OK with an approximation, here's one :http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-dba-spl.htm, or http://www.diracdelta.co.uk/science/source/a/w/aweighting/source.html#.VXrs53P6yXI

Comment: Thanks!  I'm thinking something like https://law.resource.org/pub/us/cfr/ibr/002/ansi.s1.43.1997.pdf would be good.  Because these tables will be used in a lab, ANSI is preferable.  Perhaps there are more recent versions of this, but the ANSI (https://global.ihs.com/doc_detail.cfm?&rid=ASA&item_s_key=00009513&item_key_date=881231&input_doc_number=&input_doc_title=a%20weighting&org_code=ASA#abstract) and ASA websites do not provide previews or tables of contents.  Is there a site with tables of contents or previews of the documents?  Or perhaps a site with really detailed tables from ANSI?

Answer (score 1):

There are no corresponding values from dBA, dBC, and dBZ.  The final value for each reading depends on the actual involved frequencies.

I could have a dBZ value of 95dB, caused by a single tone at 50Hz.  Measured with dBA, that would be something like 65dB.
Now, take a dBZ value of 95dB, this time from a single tone at 1000Hz.  If measured with dBA, then it will also be 95dB.

So, the sound level depends on the frequencies, and when all you have is the sound level you don't know which frequencies were present when the reading was made.  You therefore cannot translate one of the three to another of the three.

If you are looking for a table that defines dBA or dBZ, then the links provided by Dzarda ([Calculator](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-dba-spl.htm), [A-Weighting definition](http://www.diracdelta.co.uk/science/source/a/w/aweighting/source.html#.VXrs53P6yXI)) are good starting places.

You might also want to check the standard IEC 61672-1 as mentioned in the PDF you linked to.

Comment: Very true -- it does depend on frequency, as the tables you describe indicate.  That's the type of table I'm looking for.  Are there other tables online you know of?  I may be able to access the ANSI/ASA standards themselves, but sources that site the ANSI/ASA standards would be useful.